# MenuItem (Android-Programming)

Tags: android

How can I use onCreateOptionsMenu in If loop?
See this,

```
if(input.length() > 0 ){

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){  }
}
```

I would like to make a menu appear when the input which I gave in editText is having length more than 0.
Here It is showing an error that syntax error
; expected.It is showing this error before and after the round brackets i.e. (Menu menu) over here.
Please help
I'm new to android programming.

Also it is saying that I can't override this method + can't use public.

Comment: It is not what i asked for Arne Poths

Comment: you have to comment under the answer to notify the poster (he'll get notification that you said something).

Comment: The code you posted will not work in `Java`. You can't declare a method inside loops or other methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing on API level >= 11 you can try the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText input;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(input.length() > 0)
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```